# Compare value in array to value in range, if equal, insert a formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to compare values in a range to values in an array. If the values are equal, I want to insert a formula in column "O" in the corresponding row of the cell in the range that is equal to the value in the array. There is a corresponding formula for each value in the array, but for brevity I have only included the first formula in the below code. When I run the code, I receive no error message, but column "O" is not populated with any data. Any suggestions as to where my code is going wrong? I am pretty new to arrays.

```
Sub ScenarioData2()
    Dim arr1 As Variant, result As String, r As Long, rng As Range
    arr1 = Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458")

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458")
        If rng.Value = arr1(11) Then
            With Sheets("Model2")
                For r = 3 To lastrow
                .Cells(r, "O").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[]C[-6]<10,10,IF(R[]C[-1]>45,45,R[]C[-1])"
                Next r
            End With
        'Else
        End If
    Next rng

    End Sub
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code first sets rng to be equal to be a specifically identified range (AJ3:AJ14458). Your code then asks the loop to run for each 'rng' within ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458"). There is only 1 'rng' within ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458"), because you have defined rng to mean the whole worksheet in its entirety.

In fact, you should not need to set 'rng' to be equal to anything. Instead simply define it as a range; ie:

> dim rng as Range

Then, when you perform your loop, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458") will go through every 'Range' within that area (ie: it will go through every single cell).

In the future, when checking your code for similar errors, consider more than just whether an actual error message appears; have the code give you a message when you expect your desired result to be found - and then you can check what the result is actually calculated as. For example, below your "if rng.value = ...', on the next line put:

> debug.print rng.value

This will pop up a message if it finds your value. In this case, while your code doesn't have an error, it didn't find your value either. So, you know that your problem is not in your '.Cells(r, "O").FormulaR1C1 =...' line, it is in your search method.

**Edit** It also seems there are two issues with how you are telling the found cells to insert the formula. Should be as follows:

```
If rng.Value = arr1(11) Then

            For r = 3 To lastrow
                Sheets("Model2")).Range("O" & r).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-6]<10,10,IF(R[0]C[-1]>45,45,R[0]C[-1]))"
            Next r
End If
```

Note that I have added a closing bracket to the formula itself, and I have referred to .Range("O" & r) [which simplifies to O4,O5, etc. during the loop], whereas you referred to .Cells("O", r) - where O is a letter not a number, so the cells function could not find the cell you were referring to.

This worked for me so if it isn't working first check to ensure you actually have 26 entered (in number format, not text format) somewhere on column AJ.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've corrected the way I was defining my range. I've added the `debug.print rng.value` but no pop up box appears. I assume something must still be wrong with my search method.

Comment: I used this function and when I typed 26 into cell AJ4, it did find that cell. However, there were some issues with your formula method that I have resolved - see edits to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It might be in your .FormulaR1C1 format.  I've never used that before. Are you sure that is what you want to be using.  I've used the simple .Formula before with ease.

Also a tip.  I used to have to hard code my ranges until i found usedRange.

So this

```
For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Model2").Range("AJ3:AJ14458")
```

Can simply be replaced with

```
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Here is the entire loop.

```
lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Do stuff here

lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

Hope that makes your coding easier in the future.

Comment: Also I agree with @MatthewD that it is generally unwise to simply refer to an arbitrary block of data to search for; it will either slow down your code by searching unnecessarily, or it may become too small depending on how much data changes in the future.